# Extracting set of tokens from list of strings

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of strings and I want to extract all tokens into one set of tokens -not a list of sets. I need every token mixed up.

My sentences are stored as a list of strings in "sentences"

So if try:

```
words = set([])
a=set(sentences[1].split())
b=set(sentences[2].split())
a.union(b)
```

I get a and b sets in one set like this. This is what I'm searching for

```
{',', '.', '2.252', '35-1/7', '37-year-old', 'B', 'Blood', 'Fred', 'G4', 'Grauman', 'O+', 'P3-5', 'pregnancy', 'product', 'rubella', surface', 'the', 'to', 'type', 'week', 'woman'}
```

But with list comprehension

```
words = set()
[words.union(set(sent.split())) for sent in sentences]
```

The output is a list of sets, like  this

```
[{'.',  'Care',  'He',  'Intensive',  'Neonatal''}, {'.',  '2.252',  35-1/7',  '37-year-old',  'Fred',  'G4',  'Grauman','}]
```

Is there away to get what I need with some compact line of code like a list comprehension?

====

Well I just did, after list comprehension for "words",

```
a = set()
a.union(*words)
```

Comment: "compact clean line" what do you mean by that?

Comment: Well something as nice as list comprehension. Short, concrete

Comment: Just edited answer with what I did. Thanks, new to Python and appreciate advice.

Comment: @SantiagoAlcaide it's better to post what you've done as an answer to this question, and accept it. From what I know, your solution is optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sentences are in strings you can just join them and split them again.

```
set(" ".join(sentences).split())
```

turns `['A short sentence', 'A second sentence']`
into `{'A', 'second', 'sentence', 'short'}`

Answer (score 0):

How about doing:

```
set(' '.join(sentences).split())
```

Or you could try to use reduce from functools.

Comment: How is the code that you did add more information? Almost all of this is covered by the first answer.

Comment: I guess we kinda posted at the same time. I hadn't seen that answer when I was typing!